# how to fix this issue in treeview?

Tags: c#, treeview

i am import data from FTP in treeview.

in that its displaying treeview without any name(node)..only structure is visible

my code is,

```
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root"));



private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string root, string p)
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name));
            }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Comment: where is `name` and `path` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
```

Surely this should be...

```
var directoryNode = new TreeNode(p);
```

..based on your method signature?

Also `name` and `path` don't exist within your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
directoryNode.Text = name;
```

from the [MSDN TreeNode Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Text** - Gets or sets the text displayed in the label of the tree node.

try:

```
private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string root, string p)
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            directoryNode.Text = name;
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name));
            }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(file.Name);
                tn.Text = file.Name
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(tn));
            }
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

I am unsure where the variables "name" and "path" are coming from? I guess they equate to root and p? I will leave that for you to clear up

Comment: Set the text property to whatever you would like the node to display. It is very unclear what you are asking I suggest you revise your question to make it clearer

Comment: i will explain clearly...i am just display the files from ftp in treeview..for that i am facing this issue,it will read my files from ftp,but structure does not have name.